# How to fill in mediapipe landmarks using opengl es android

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer, mediapipe

i have a landmarks for lips(i got from MediaPipe),

Currently, i created the triangle coordinated and then i tried triangle_strip, triangle_fan to fill the connected lines which i got from mediapipe.

is that approach is correct or is any other proper approach there to fill all the connected lines ?

I'm Using mediapipe SOlutions API example - Source Here -> https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/e0a254789a1ec05f3c09411b45a6c59d0ed3075e/mediapipe/examples/android/solutions/facemesh/src/main/java/com/google/mediapipe/examples/facemesh/FaceMeshResultGlRenderer.java#L154

Comment: any success in this?